# How to get the gradient for margins alone when using tcolorbox environment

Tags: tcolorbox, gradient

I am creating one new environment  with tcolorbox.sty, those environment style would be gradient only on the left side margin

How to get this style in tcolorbox

MY MWE

```
 \documentclass{book}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\tcbset{exstyle/.style={
enhanced,breakable,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,sharp corners,interior style={left color=black!9, right color=black!0},width=30pc,
left skip=-110pt,right=10pt,left=110pt,before skip=14pt,after skip=14pt,colframe=black!40
}}


\newenvironment{shadeexample}{\begin{tcolorbox}[exstyle]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadeexample}
 In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of

  In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of

   In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of

    In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of
\end{shadeexample}

\end{document}
```

i need the out put like below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! You may add the shading via `overlay`. (I am a bit concerned about your box overshooting on the right, maybe you want to decrease the width?)

```
 \documentclass{book}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\tcbset{exstyle/.style={
enhanced,breakable,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,sharp corners,
interior style={fill=white},width=30pc,%<- remove?
left skip=-110pt,right=10pt,left=110pt,
before skip=14pt,after skip=14pt,
colframe=black!40,%enlarge left=110pt,
overlay={\path[left color=black!9, right color=black!0]
(frame.north west) rectangle ([xshift=110pt]frame.south west);}
}}


\newenvironment{shadeexample}{\begin{tcolorbox}[exstyle]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadeexample}
 In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of

  In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of

   In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of

    In this chapter the focus is on the basic features of such  transformation processes  themselves, with minimal regard to the notion of solving specific problems. The focus is on understanding procedures for casting and potentially reorganizing  a linear transformation into a form that is convenient for addressing whatever problem is at hand.   In this process, it becomes important not only to treat the linear transformation when it is expressed within a particular basis, but also to recognize  when it is in fact more useful to treat it in a way that is independent of basis.   For this purpose, certain notational distinctions are introduced on page.  Once these concepts are in place,  the  issue of solving specific problems of
\end{shadeexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]